# Почему класс valarray работает медленно и как правильно делать векторизацию вычислений?

Tags: c++, c

Сравниваю скорость перемножения двух векторов **valarray** и последующего присвоения третьему вектору, скорость перемножения двух массивов и присвоение результата третьему в обычном цикле и скорость перемножения двух массивов и присвоение результата третьему с использованием векторных расширений. С векторизацией я не знаком и делаю это в первый раз.

Получил следующие значения средних времён вычислений, приведённых к массивам типа **double** длинной 1 млрд.: valarray - 4.30241 сек.; в обычном цикле - 1.10416 сек.; с использованием векторных расширений - 1.14358 сек.

Результат получен на основе 300 прогонов для массивов длинной 20 млн.
Конфигурация Release и платформа x64.
Процессор 4000 серии Ryzen, если это имеет значение.

**Сам вопрос:** почему valarray работает так медленно и почему при обычном перемножении в цикле результат лучше, чем с использованием векторных расширений?

На вторую часть вопроса я частично получил ответ тут: http://ssd.sscc.ru/sites/default/files/content/attach/317/lecture2015_10_vectorization.pdf
Но тогда скорости должны были быть как минимум равны, а с использованием векторных расширений получилось медленнее, значит я что-то не правильно делаю.

Ниже сам код программы.
Реализацию класса Timer взял от сюда: https://ravesli.com/urok-129-tajming-koda-vremya-vypolneniya-programmy/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <chrono>

class Timer{
private:
    using clock_t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    using second_t = std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1>>;

    std::chrono::time_point<clock_t> m_beg;

public:
    Timer() : m_beg(clock_t::now()) {
    }

    void reset() {
        m_beg = clock_t::now();
    }

    double elapsed() const {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<second_t>(clock_t::now() - m_beg).count();
    }
};

#define _mm256_mul_t _mm256_mul_pd
#define type double
#define __m256_t __m256d

int main() {

    Timer t;
    double t_1{ 0. }, t_2{ 0. }, t_3{ 0. };

    size_t m{ 5000000 }, n_cyc{ 10 }, st{ sizeof(type) }, step{ 256 / 8 / st }, n{ m * step };

    std::valarray<type> varr_1(type(2), n), varr_2(type(3), n), varr_3(type(0), n);

    type *arr_1{ new type[n] }, *arr_2{ new type[n] }, *arr_3{ new type[n] };
    for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < n; ++i) {
        arr_1[i] = type(2);
        arr_2[i] = type(3);
        arr_3[i] = type(0);
    }


    //первый тест

    for (size_t count{ 0 }; count < n_cyc; ++count) {

        t.reset();

        varr_3 = varr_1 * varr_2;

        t_1 += t.elapsed();

        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < varr_3.size(); ++i) {
            varr_3[i] = type(0);
        }

    }


    //второй тест

    for (size_t count{ 0 }; count < n_cyc; ++count) {

        t.reset();

        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < n; ++i) {
            arr_3[i] = arr_1[i] * arr_2[i];
        }

        t_2 += t.elapsed();

        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < n; ++i) {
            arr_3[i] = type(0);
        }

    }


    //третий тест

    for (size_t count{ 0 }; count < n_cyc; ++count) {

        t.reset();

        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < n; i += step) {
            *(__m256_t *)(arr_3 + i) = _mm256_mul_t(*(__m256_t *)(arr_1 + i), *(__m256_t *)(arr_2 + i));
        }

        t_3 += t.elapsed();

        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < n; ++i) {
            arr_3[i] = type(0);
        }

    }


    //результат

    t_1 /= double(n_cyc) * double(n) * 1.e-9;
    t_2 /= double(n_cyc) * double(n) * 1.e-9;
    t_3 /= double(n_cyc) * double(n) * 1.e-9;

    std::cout << "valarray\t" << t_1
        << "\nindex\t\t" << t_2
        << "\nm256_t\t\t" << t_3
        << std::endl;


    delete[] arr_1;
    delete[] arr_2;
    delete[] arr_3;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128306/discussion-on-question-by-maiq-the-liar---valarray--).